# Java - Search String For Byte Code

Tags: java, byte

I have tried many searches to find a way to search a string for byte code. Here is an example:

```
String stringThatHasBytes = "hello world hello world[B@9304b1";

If stringThatHasBytes . Does have bytes {
return true or false
}
```

Is there a method that can search a String for bytes?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you looking for a regex to match default Java Object toString output? Do you need to match *any* type shortcuts, or just [B@[0-9a-f]{6}, or...?

Comment: It looks like you are concatenating a string with a `byte[]`, because `"[B@9304b1"` looks like the output of `toString()` on a byte array. Why? What "byte code" are you looking for in that string?

Comment: If i understand correctly, you need to define a pattern that will match this String with _byte code_ in it. So, the most likely is to use a `regepx` and the [String#matches](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) method.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? What is the bigger goal? This sounds like a severe [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/133242) to me.

Comment: The OP has not attempted to explain what he is asking after 1 hour of waiting.  Voting to close as "unintelligible".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this, in short. Because the printing of a byte changes everytime you print it out. Printing out the bytes doesn't print the actual bytes and it's meaningless if you're looking for exact comparison of bytes.

However, if you only look for any byte printing in the string, just control for `[B@`s in the string and return true.

```
String stringThatHasBytes = "hello world hello world[B@9304b1";

if (stringThatHasBytes.indexOf("[B@") >= 0)
    return true;
} else return false;
```

**EDIT:**

If you need ways of printing bytes in a meaningful way, you should convert the bytes to some meaningful text such as:

```
public static String convertByteArrayToHexString(byte[] b) {
    if (b != null) {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(2 * b.length);

        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; ++i) {
            final String t = Integer.toHexString(b[i]);
            final int l = t.length();
            if (l > 2) {
                s.append(t.substring(l - 2));
            } else {
                if (l == 1) {
                    s.append("0");
                }
                s.append(t);
            }
        }

        return s.toString();
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

see if this help

```
        byte[] myByteArray = new byte[5];

        myByteArray[0] = 'a';
        myByteArray[1] = 'b';
        myByteArray[2] = 'c';
        myByteArray[3] = 'd';
        myByteArray[4] = 'e';


        for (byte x : myByteArray)
            System.out.println(x);


        String myString = "abcde";

        System.out.println(myString.equals(new String(myByteArray)));
```

Comment: Did you mean to cast those `char`s to `byte`s? Because currently you have both a redundant cast and a type inconsistency.

Answer (score 0):

Would contains be too simple of an answer for you?

```
boolean hasBytes = str.contains("[B@");
```

If so let me know I'll show you some good regex! but that should be sufficient.

Comment: How do I get the entire byte part?